# regular expression comparing a record with a previous record

Tags: regex, notepad++, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I am in need of a regular expression to search within a text file and find every row that starts with "CD" when the previous row does NOT start with "CR".

In the sample data below, notice at the end where there are CD rows that have no preceding CR record.  I need my search to find those CD rows.

```
HDPM0021535 11ABC CO. D 
CRVA MC OP-MATHER CA 1053 
CD1010 BD5275555
TR+00000001+00000000+0000024760 
HDPM0021535 11ABC CO. D 
CROMNICARE RENO 48308 9475 
CD3055 BO9182000
CROCR OF SANTA ROSA 48218 879 
CD3055 BC9832555
TR+00000002+00000000+0000000695 
HDPM0021535 11ABC CO. D 
CD2037 AF7944888
CD2037 AF7944888
TR+00000002+00000001-0000000089 
TT+00000008+0000196660200
```

Thank you!

Comment: In what language / environment?

Comment: Right now, I'm just searching plain text files using the Regular Expression option in Notepad++ on a Windows 7 machine.  Eventually, I will build an Oracle SQL report to flag these from the database automatically.

Comment: Try `(?:\G(?!^)\R?|^(?!CR).*\R)\KCD.*`. No idea how to catch the first line though.

Comment: GJ. Just remove `(?!^)` part. @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Yeah, `(?:\G\R?|^(?!CR).*\R)\KCD.*` might be what OP is looking for.

Comment: Wiktor, revo, This is perfect!  Thank you so much for the quick-turnaround!  Much appreciated

Comment: @StevenKerper: I posted this as an answer, please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you may use

```
(?:\G\R?|^(?!CR).*\R)\KCD.*
```

**Details**:

- `(?:\G\R?|^(?!CR).*\R)` - either the start of document or end of previous successful match (`\G`) followed with an optional linebreak (`\R?`), or start of a line (`^`) not followed with `CR` (`(?!CR)`) followed with any 0+ chars other than line break chars (`.*`) followed with a line break (`\R`)
- `\K` -  a match reset operator discarding the text matched so far
- `CD.*` - `CD` followed with any 0+ chars other than line break chars (*`.` matches newline* must be OFF)

[image]